# Runtime of Binet's Formula

Tags: algorithm, runtime

So I'm computing the Fibonacci numbers using Binet's formula with the GNU MP library. I'm trying to work out the asymptotic runtime of the algorithm.

For Fib(n) I'm setting the variables to n bits of precision; thus I believe multiplying two numbers is n Log(n). The exponentiation is, I believe n Log(n) multiplications; so I believe I have n Log(n)Log(n Log(n)). Is this correct, in both in assumptions (multiplying floating point numbers and number of multiplications in exponentiation with integer exponent) and in conclusion?

If my precision is high, and I use precision g(n); then I think this reduces to g(n) Log(g(n)); however I think g(n) should be g(n)=n Log(phi)+1; which shouldn't have a real impact on the asymptotics.

Comment: Calculation involves just a multiplication and a en exponentiation right? exp(x * log(\phi))  (keep precomputed log(\phi) ).

Comment: You are using `n` to represent both a number and its bit-count :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with your evaluation.

The cost of long multiplies depends on the algorithm in use. Can be O(n^1.585) [Karatsuba], or O(n.Log(n).Log(Log(n))) [Schönhage–Strassen], or other.

The cost of exponentiation can be made O(Log(n)) multiplies for exponent n.